# Correlation Heatmap using Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I am plotting a correlation heat map using Seaborn. Correlation ranges from 0.6-1. I am using the following code. Trouble I have is I am getting the same color in all the cells. How can I enforce more divergence in color?

```
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr, dtype=bool))

# Set up the matplotlib figure
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(11, 9))

# Generate a custom diverging colormap
cmap = sns.diverging_palette(20, 220, n=256, as_cmap=True)

# Draw the heatmap with the mask and correct aspect ratio
sns.heatmap(corr, 
            mask=mask, 
            cmap=cmap, 
            vmax=.3, 
            center=0,
            square=True, 
            linewidths=.5,
            annot = True,
            fmt='.2f', 
            annot_kws={'size': 10},
            cbar_kws={"shrink": .75})

plt.title('Asset Correlation Matrix')
plt.tight_layout()
ax.tick_params(axis = 'x', labelsize = 8)
ax.set_ylim(len(corr)+1, -1)
```

[image: Correlation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the vmin and vmax params for sns.heatmap(...) as outlined here (https://python-graph-gallery.com/92-control-color-in-seaborn-heatmaps/).

Since your values range from 0.6 to 1.0, you can try setting vmin = 0.55 and vmax = 1.0 to limit the color range to those values.